# How can I get a Youtube video (to get data such as duration, publication date, etc) using the video URL? C#

Tags: c#, api, video, youtube, youtube-api

I've been looking into the Youtube API but it's not clear to me how (if at all) I can get a specific video by URL. I have an API key and a Youtube username. From there I'm at a loss.

I have a video on my page that is inside an iframe like so:

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/jwGFGP8Z0Ps?wmode=opaque&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I need to get the video data using that URL (or using the info that I have in the URL; would I just use the `jwGFGP8Z0Ps` part?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you would grab the video ID from the URL, then make a call to YouTube's **Videos: list** api call for that video ID.

Start here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#request

Check the examples.